# Pygame app created with py2app won't run

Tags: python, macos, pygame, py2app

I'm creating an OSX game, 'doughnuts', using pygame and currently attempting to turn it into a standalone app using py2app. I followed the tutorial and have disabled argv-emulation since it isn't supported for 64-bit apps and I don't need it anyway. After creating the app and launching it, I get a popup window saying 'doughnuts Error', which gives me an option to open the console, but no information apart from 'doughnuts Error' can be found there. This happens both with and without alias mode, and the file doughnuts.py runs fine on its own. What do I do next?

My setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['doughnuts.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': False}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: Can you post your setup.py? Also, have you tried PyInstaller as a possible alternative?

Comment: Posted my setup.py. I've just given PyInstaller a go, but in the dist directory it's only generated a folder with tons of stuff inside, no .app file. I'm a little confused about this.

Comment: You need to run PyInstaller with the --windowed command and point it to your Python main before it'll generate the right app bundle.

Comment: Also, do you use any fonts in your script?

Comment: There are no fonts used in my script. I've tried using the --windowed command, and now I'm getting a problem "no such file or directory". This is what I'm typing:`python pyinstaller.py doughnuts.py --windowed` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ```python pyinstaller.py --windowed doughnuts.py```

Comment: Yep, still getting "Execution failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

Comment: Would try two more things. 1. try running the .app bundle from the command line (ex: ```open Doughnuts.app```) 2. make a list of all of the external assets your program uses and try removing every one of them to see if it'll run without external assets.

Comment: I've just noticed, the line after which the error occurs is this one: `Executing - upx --best -q /Users/SeanDuffy/Library/Application Support/pyinstaller/bincache01_py27/_struct.so`, which doesn't exist since the Library isn't located in my user directory, but in the root of my drive. I suppose there isn't much I can do about this.

Comment: See [My py2app app will not open. What's the problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470377/my-py2app-app-will-not-open-whats-the-problem)